# how to display time every 15mins with a loop?

Tags: c, for-loop, time

My assignments requires me to display a starting time (hh:mm:ss) of user's input and travelling distance. The taxi is going in 90km/h. So ideally, I would want the program to display the time (15mins interval), from starting time to end time but in mm:ss format.

My approach is that I convert the starting time and end time to seconds, and I used a for loop. My interval would be i+900 (15mins in seconds). However, my for loop keeps running and never ends. Anyone can help me out ?

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/G9Ycg.png)  <--- Expected output

My current code

```
    int hour, min, sec, minhour, newmin, timesec, endtime; //ignore irrelevant variables
    float distance, remdis, remdisb, firstfare, secondfare, fare;

    printf("Input your starting travelling time in 24hrs clock (hh mm ss): ");
    scanf("%d %d %d", &hour, &min, &sec);
    printf("Input your total travelling distance (km): ");
    scanf("%f", &distance);
    minhour = hour * 60;
    newmin = min + minhour;
    printf("Your starting time is %02d:%02d:%02d or %02d:%02d (mm:ss)\n", hour, min, sec, newmin, sec);
    printf("Your total travelling distance is %.1fkm or %.0fm\n", distance, distance*1000);

    timesec = hour*3600 + min*60 + sec;
    endtime = timesec + ((distance/90)*3600);

    printf("Starting time | Fare(%.1fkm)", distance);

    for (int i=timesec; i<=endtime; i+900)
    {
        min = i/60;
        sec = i - min;
        printf("%d:%d   |  $XX.yy\n", min, sec);
    }
```

Comment: The solution you provided can't really work because you don't know how much execution time the for loop will take so try `sleep(15*60);` in a while loop with an end condition of 'when the current time >= endtime. Note that you have to include `#include <unistd.h>` for sleep to work.

Comment: hmm I'm not experienced in sleep though. Do you have any other recommendations ?

Comment: you have some issues with your code. check out my answer below.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> However, my for loop keeps running and never ends
>
> ```c
>      for (int i=timesec; i<=endtime; i+900)
>                                      ~~~~~~
> ```

Use `i+=900`, not `i+900` here.

Answer (score 0):

Try this out:

```
    int hour, min, sec, minhour, newmin, timesec, endtime; //ignore irrelevant variables
    float distance, remdis, remdisb, firstfare, secondfare, fare;

    printf("Input your starting travelling time in 24hrs clock (hh mm ss): ");
    scanf("%d %d %d", &hour, &min, &sec);
    printf("Input your total travelling distance (km): ");
    scanf("%f", &distance);
    minhour = hour * 60;
    newmin = min + minhour;
    printf("Your starting time is %02d:%02d:%02d or %02d:%02d (mm:ss)\n", hour, min, sec, newmin, sec);
    printf("Your total travelling distance is %.1fkm or %.0fm\n", distance, distance*1000);

    endtime = newmin + ((distance*60)/90);

    printf("Starting time | Fare(%.1fkm)\n", distance);

    for (int i=newmin; i<=endtime; i+=15)
    {
        hour = i/60;
        min = i % 60;
        printf("%02d:%02d   |  $XX.yy\n", hour, min);
    }
```